# How do i create a background for a heading tag in html/css like this?

Tags: html, css

[image: image, click here].

Trying to create a background for a heading tag like the image above. Anyone know how?

Tried using clip path, and svg path but didn't get it right. Would appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this. Thanks!

```css
/* First try*/
.splash {
  background-color: #f5e2d1;
  clip-path: ellipse(75% 23% at 53% 30%);
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Second try, didn't quite understand this one and tried playing with the numbers but didn't get the shape i want */
.splash {
  background-color: #f5e2d1;
  clip-path: path('M50 0 C20 20, 20 70, 50 50, 80 70, 80 20, 50 0 Z');
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <h3 lass="clipped">Education</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: You can draw the shape and save it as a transparent background PNG. Then, use the image as the background image of the button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Raptor! I tried drawing the shape in Figma and it worked wonders :).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Will this meet your needs

```css
.fancy-text {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff9800, #e91e63);
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-text">
  Raky
</div>
```

You can play with these

```
 width: 15%;
  height: 10px;
  display: flex;
```

to shape as you like it better

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Raky! Not quite what I need, but a very big step forward! I need the bubble to be a little indented in some spots, so not entirly like a circle/ellipse. I will try to play around with your code and see if i can make it more alike the image. Thanks a lot for the code!

Answer (score -2):

@CheepSheep, Looking at what you attempted, Heres something more for you...

```js
const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');
const fancyText = document.querySelector('.fancy-text');


function resizeSplash() {
  const textWidth = fancyText.offsetWidth;
  splash.style.width = textWidth + 'px';
}


resizeSplash();
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeSplash);
```

```css
.splash {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f5e2d1;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.clipped {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fancy-text {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff9800, #e91e63);
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <h3 class="clipped">
    <p class="fancy-text">Raky's Education </p>
  </h3>
</div>

<div class="splash">
  <h3 class="clipped fancy-text">Raky's Education</h3>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="splash">
  <h3 class="clipped">
    <p class="fancy-text">Raky's Education </p>
  </h3>
</div>
<br> <br>
<div class="splash">
  <h3 class="clipped fancy-text">Raky's Education</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: How about trying to replicate the background in the given image?

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/5211833). Besides, I did leave a comment ...

Comment: Did i do something wrong? o.o I accepted the answer and gave a up vote like you told me to, but the upvote didn't go through since I'm new. It just says "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: Also thanks Raky for another solution provided! Will check it out. Also as an answer to Tim R as well, I tried drawing an image in Figma as a background image, which seems to be the most accurate so far. Will be trying the new solution provided by Raky and see how it goes. Once again, thanks for the answers Raky!

Comment: Raky, I suspect you received downvotes because you showed only how to have a symmetrical oval background instead of the odd-shaped background that is shown in the image, which was the purpose of the question.